# Debian virtual machine no connectivity with two network adapters

Tags: debian, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running several Debian 12 (both host and guests) virtual machines using VirtualBox.
All of a sudden, today they started having connectivity issues (i.e., I couldn't ping 8.8.8.8). I recently upgraded from Debian 11 to Debian 12.

All virtual machines have two network adapters:

- One NAT network adapter
- One Host-only network adapter

After some testing, I have found out that removing the Host-only network adapter restores connectivity. What could be the issue? It's like the systems are ignoring the NAT network adapter and using the Host-only network adapter that has no connectivity.

How can I debug that?

Comment: Well, check `ip r` (and maybe also `ip ru` for paranoia).

Comment: Nothing in computing happens `All of a sudden` without a direct cause. `I recently upgraded from Debian 11 to Debian 12.` what is the timeframe between this upgrade and this `all of a sudden` failure? Did the failure happen immediately after rebooting after upgrading from 11 to 12? If not, then the upgrade is completely irrelevant

Comment: The failure happened some weeks after upgrading. ip -r didn’t show any anomalies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I cannot explain why and how (if anybody can, please edit my answer).

Edit `/etc/networking/interfaces`

Previous broken version:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.56.103
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.56.1


allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

New working version:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.56.103
        netmask 255.255.255.0


allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

After that either reboot or issue `service networking restart`

---

EDIT:

Assuming eth1 is the interface that connects to the host-only network, you were never supposed to configure a `gateway` on it (in another sense, a default route that makes use of it), since it is not typically used for Internet traffics (although AFAIK technically you can set things up and use that for it) and apparently, you never meant to do so anyway.

I don't know what's the heuristic in the kernel in picking a route among multiple ones with same "coverage" *and* same metric, but I'm pretty sure from the user point of view the behavior is likely more or less indeterministic, let alone the one from dhcp might even be added with higher metric value (i.e. lower precedence) anyway.

Comment: You are the man